# Unity 3D: 2D physics for a multiplayer game using Photon

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

I am currently struggling to figure out how to push a cart.
To help you imagine what I'm trying to achieve, I'll try to give my best description.
Imagine you have 3 friends and a rectangle. Each of your friends including you grabbed a rectangle by the corner and you want to move it to the specified position. You are glued to this corner meaning you move with a rectangle as it's pushed or pulled. You can push it in the same direction as your friends or opposite, the forces are applied by each of you into that corner (if 2 of you were to push up and 2 of you down, the force is zero, if 4 of you push up, its 4 times as strong as if one would push it).
So my question is, how do I make the physics for the players (friends) and a cart (rectangle)?
The game is 2d and you have a view from the top, similar to the "Overcooked" game.
A concept without an actual script is also fine for me, cause it's hard for me to even think of how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to calculate the forces for each player (as a vector2 or vector3) and then apply those to your cart object. the physics engine will handle calculating which way the cart should move on its own.

You can then attach the player objects to the cart, and control their movement that way.